# Using the typeof operator for comparison looping through an array. Why are my Values not being pushed to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, typeof

```js
/* TASK: create a function that merges an array of arrays into one, and then 
pushes the strings into the str array and push the numbers into the num array.
 The values are not being pushed into the str or nums array even though the typeof operator is working in the if statement. Why? */

let ans = (arr) => {
  let str = [];
  let nums = [];
  let inOneArr = arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
   return a.concat(b);
  })
  alert(inOneArr);
  for(let i = 0; i < inOneArr.length; i++) {
   if(inOneArr[i] == typeof(string)) {
     str.push(inOneArr[i]);
    } else if (inOneArr[i] == typeof(number)) {
     nums.push(inOneArr[i]);
    }
  }
  alert(str);
  alert(nums);
}

ans([["strings","bolls","netflix",1,4,5],["felix",22,"@gmail.com"],[32,"@#@@!","Chris"]])
```

Comment: What is your question? If there is a problem with your code, what is it?

Comment: the values are not being pushed to the str array or the nums array. even though in the loop they are giving the correct typeOf values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The syntax of typeof is:**

```
         +----- This is the operand to be evaluated
         |
         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
typeof [(object | value returned from a function, Etc)].
```

> [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
>
> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

**The `typeof` operator is followed by its operand:**

```
typeof operand
or
typeof (operand)
```

`operand` is an expression representing the object or primitive whose type is to be returned.

```js
let ans = (arr) => {
  let str = [];
  let nums = [];
  let inOneArr = arr.reduce((a,b)=>{
   return a.concat(b);
  })
  alert(inOneArr);
  for(let i = 0; i < inOneArr.length; i++) {
//                +---- Operand
//                |
//                v
   if(typeof inOneArr[i] === 'string') {
     str.push(inOneArr[i]);
//                    +---- Operand
//                    |
//                    v      
    } else if (typeof inOneArr[i] === 'number') {
     nums.push(inOneArr[i]);
    }
  }
  alert(str);
  alert(nums);
}

ans([["strings","bolls","netflix",1,4,5],["felix",22,"@gmail.com"],[32,"@#@@!","Chris"]])
```

Answer (score 3):

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is a key word which doesn't require brackets, and returns a string of the type; for example `"string"` or `"boolean"`.

It should be used on the elements you wish to find the type of. Not like: `typeof(number)`.

```
function ans() {
    let str = [];
    let nums = [];
    let inOneArr = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.concat(b);
    })
    alert(inOneArr);
    for (let i = 0; i < inOneArr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof inOneArr[i] === "string") {
            str.push(inOneArr[i]);
        } else if (typeof inOneArr[i] === "number") {
            nums.push(inOneArr[i]);
        }
        alert(str);
        alert(nums);
    }
}
ans([
    ["strings", "bolls", "netflix", 1, 4, 5],
    ["felix", 22, "@gmail.com"],
    [32, "@#@@!", "Chris"]
]);
```